# DT package: styleColorbar() not working on Android tablets

Tags: javascript, android, r, shiny, dt

I have developed an R `shiny` app using the excellent `DT` package to handle the datatables. One of the tables uses the `styleColorbar` helper function which produces coloured bars in table cells proportionate to the value of each cell.

This works just fine in Chrome and Firefox running in Windows, but the coloured bars do not display when running in Chrome or the native browser on a Sony Experia Android tablet.

This is also the case on the demonstration web-page here: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html. 
So I don't think it is an issue specific to my use of the code.

The function is basically a JS wrapper...and I have precisely zero knowledge of JS.

```
styleColorBar = function(data, color, angle=90) {
  rg = range(data, na.rm = TRUE, finite = TRUE)
  r1 = rg[1]; r2 = rg[2]; r = r2 - r1
  JS(sprintf(
    "isNaN(parseFloat(value)) || value <= %s ? '' : 'linear-gradient(%sdeg, transparent ' + (%s - value)/%s * 100 + '%%, %s ' + (%s - value)/%s * 100 + '%%)'",
  r1, angle, r2, r, color, r2, r
  ))
}
```

I am using it in the following context:

```
dat = DT::datatable(diversity,
      options = list(
        scrollX = TRUE, 
        scrollY = 400,
        autoWidth = TRUE,
        columnDefs = list(
          list(visible = FALSE, targets = hidden)
        )
      ),
      style = "bootstrap", 
      class = "table-striped table-compact", 
      extensions = c("FixedColumns"),
      )
       %>%
formatStyle(
      c(1),
      background = styleColorBar(c(0,diversity[,1]), 'olivedrab'),
      backgroundSize = '99% 90%',
      backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
      backgroundPosition = 'center'
    )
```

Can anyone suggest what might be wrong and a workaround for this to work on Android platforms?

EDIT:
I believe this may be a problem with the linear-gradient syntax, which has compatibility problems with earlier versions of Android. However, I tested it on a Android 4.1 tablet, so not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised the same question on Github and yihui's response can be found here: https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/222. He reckon's that the issue can be solved by using `-webkit-`. Other online info also suggests that this should work on older Android systems. I'll post his code here to help others:

```
styleColorBar2 = function(...) {
  sub('linear-gradient', '-webkit-linear-gradient', styleColorBar(...))
}
```

I'm not sure how to detect what version of Android is running on a system from within R, but that is a separate question.